# I would like to know how I can add attributes to the activity entity

Tags: attributes, task, dynamics-crm

I would like to know how I can add attributes to the activity entity.
Currently the default activities are
Email, Task, Letter, Fax, Phone call, Appointment, Campaign, Service
I would like to add more to the pick-list. I have already tried going into customizing entities > Activities > Attributes > Activity type code. Once I get to the list of attributes within the Activity tasks, The Pick list is locked and you are not able to modify or add. How would I go about adding attributes to the pick list?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. CRM has a set list of activities, and you can't add or remove anything from that list.

Comment: http://rc.crm.dynamics.com/rc/regcont/en_us/op/articles/activities.aspx

I found this article and it says that it can be done, but it does not tell you how to do it. If you would read it and let me know what you think, it would be great. Yes, I guess you could say that what I know how to add attributes to an entity, it is the fact that where you would normally go to do that is locked. I have full access so the security privileges are not an issue.

Comment: Some attributes on the Activity are customizable, this is true. And as Churchy said you can add more attributes to individual activity entities. However, you cannot modify this particular picklist, or add any new additional activity types. You'll have to reuse one of the existing types as David mentions.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add new activity type.

What I (and others) often do is reuse certain type for another reason. I usually reuse Fax, which is rarely used.

Comment: There are custom activity types coming in CRM 2011 so you won't have to do re-purpose activity types any more.

Comment: Yes, CRM 2011 will offer quite a few useful additions so we don't have to use workarounds. But CRM 4 will be around for few years more...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add attributes to all the activities at the same time, you can't, but you can add attributes to all the activities independently.

... just in case that somebody is really looking to "add attributes to the activity entity" and find this question.